# SQL Server Express 2008 Connection String does not appear in web.config

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need some help here.

I am using VS 2010 Pro. When I create an empty ASP.NET Website and add users to it either through:

1. Asp.Net Configuration Wizard or
2. through a Register.aspx page with createuser wizard

everthing works fine. I get an ASPNETDB.MDF in my App_Data folder. The membership and roles, login and logout all work as expected.

The problem is that the web.config file does not show the connection string to SQL Server Express database file. Also the membership element etc are also missing.

However, if I create an ASP.NET Website (not an empty ASP.NET website), then web.config file carries all the information.

I have tried this on

1. Windows 7 Ultimate with VS 2010 Pro and IIS 7.5
2. Windows XP Professional with VS 2010 Pro with VS builtin development server

Same results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help

I have found the answer.

The connection string for the ASPNETDB.MDF does not appear in web.config.

The application uses a machine wide connection string defined in the machine.config file.

For more details check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218942/sql-server-express-2008-connection-string-missing-in-web-config).